# Automatic saving of picture taken from android device to htdocs folder (xxamp)

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an android app to capture image and I want to save it directly to the htdocs in xxamp. How can I automatically save the picture in htdocs folder?. I want to save the image directly there so that I could easily store the filename in my mysql database and retrieve it when i want. I dont have any codes yet. I want to know the process and codes or link for automatic saving in computer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How much are you paying?

Comment: So you have xxamp installed on your device!? And what is the path to the htdocs folder exactly?

Comment: No. I have xxamp installed in my computer, i want to ask if it is possible to automatically save the captured image from my android device to my computer.